# Having trouble with averageifs exception on a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, average

I have the dataframe successfully performing the equivalent of an averageifs statement in excel, but I don't know how to add this "exclude" syntax. I want the average of all Units_Ordered for that Customer_Number and Product, except on that Order_Number row. I'm thinking it would be something like a `Where Not`, but I don't really know how to implement.

Logically, this excludes that specific order from the average in case that order is an error (the entire purpose of the report).

```
#SQL Query
SQLCommand =("SELECT DISTINCT RMORHP.ORHORDNUM AS 'Order_Number', RMORHP.ORHCRTDTE AS 'Order_Create_Date', RMORHP.ORHCRTUSR AS 'Created By', CONCAT(RMORHP.ORHCUSCHN,'-',RMORHP.ORHCUSNUM) AS 'Customer_Number', RMORHP.ORHCUSCHN AS 'Chain ID', RMORHP.ORHCUSNUM AS 'Cust ID', RMCUSP.CUSCUSNAM AS 'Customer Name', RMORDP.ORDITMNUM AS 'Product', RMITMP.ITMLNGDES AS 'Product Name', RMORDP.ORDADJQTY AS 'Units_Ordered'"
             " FROM BIDW_DataLake.eRMS.RMCUSP RMCUSP, BIDW_DataLake.eRMS.RMITMP RMITMP, BIDW_DataLake.eRMS.RMORDP RMORDP, BIDW_DataLake.eRMS.RMORHP RMORHP"
             " WHERE (RMORHP.ORHCRTDTE Between ? And ?) AND (RMCUSP.CUSCUSCHN=RMORHP.ORHCUSCHN) AND (RMCUSP.CUSCUSNUM=RMORHP.ORHCUSNUM) AND (RMORHP.ORHORDNUM=RMORDP.ORDORDNUM) AND (RMORDP.ORDITMNUM=RMITMP.ITMITMNUM) AND (RMCUSP.CUSDFTDCN=505)")

df = pd.read_sql_query(SQLCommand, cnxn, params=(qtrprior,today,))

df['Avg_Units_Ordered'] = (df.groupby(['Customer_Number','Product'])['Units_Ordered'].transform('mean')).round(0)
df['Var_From_Avg'] = df['Avg_Units_Ordered'] - df['Units_Ordered']
df['Var_From_Avg'] = df['Var_From_Avg'].abs().round(0)


df2 = df.query('Order_Create_Date == @today')
df2 = df2.query('Var_From_Avg >= @MinVar')
df2 = df2.query('Avg_Units_Ordered * @MinMul <= Units_Ordered')
```

EDIT: Here is a visual example of some of the rows. I want it to run an average based on product and customer, which it does, but also excluding that order number from the average, which it does not. Maybe a filter where it only looks at previous date ranges (ie today -1). That would work. Like `Having Order_Create_Date < today`. I just don't know how to script that.

[image]

Comment: Can you give some sample df and output df ?

Answer (score 1):

How about subsetting the dataframe before you perform the average operation?

Something like

`df[df.Order_Create_Date < Today]` and then performing the mean and group by calculations?

Comment: How would I then run my averageifs calc?

Comment: Once you subset the data set, you only have records that have the `Order_Create_Date` having values less than the current date. So you can simply average then.